# SVG doesn't animate first time loading in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, animation, firefox, svg

I have an svg

```
<svg class="svg_el" viewbox="0 0 100 100" preserveaspectratio="none">
  <path class="overlay_path">
    <animate attributeName="d" values="M 0 0 V 0 C 50 0 50 0 100 0 V 0 H 0;                         M 0 25 V 25 C 50 15 50 60 100 50 V 0 H 0;                         M 0 50 V 50 C 50 50 50 85 100 80 V 0 H 0;                         M 0 100 V 100 C 50 100 50 100 100 100 V 0 H 0" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
<animate attributeName="d" values="M 0 0 C 50 0 50 0 100 0 V 100 H 0;                         M 0 25 C 50 15 50 60 100 50 V 100 H 0;                         M 0 50 C 50 50 50 85 100 80 V 100 H 0;                         M 0 100 C 50 100 50 100 100 100 V 100 H 0" dur="0.4s" begin="reveal.begin+0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
  </path>
  <path class="overlay_path">
    <animate attributeName="d" values="M 0 0 V 0 C 50 0 50 0 100 0 V 0 H 0;                         M 0 25 V 25 C 50 15 50 60 100 50 V 0 H 0;                         M 0 50 V 50 C 50 50 50 85 100 80 V 0 H 0;                         M 0 100 V 100 C 50 100 50 100 100 100 V 0 H 0" dur="0.4s" begin="0.1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
    <animate attributeName="d" values="M 0 0 C 50 0 50 0 100 0 V 100 H 0;                         M 0 25 C 50 15 50 60 100 50 V 100 H 0;                         M 0 50 C 50 50 50 85 100 80 V 100 H 0;                         M 0 100 C 50 100 50 100 100 100 V 100 H 0" dur="0.4s" begin="reveal.begin+0.1s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
  </path>
  <path class="overlay_path">
    <animate attributeName="d" values="M 0 0 V 0 C 50 0 50 0 100 0 V 0 H 0;                         M 0 25 V 25 C 50 15 50 60 100 50 V 0 H 0;                         M 0 50 V 50 C 50 50 50 85 100 80 V 0 H 0;                         M 0 100 V 100 C 50 100 50 100 100 100 V 0 H 0" dur="0.4s" begin="0.2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
    <animate id="reveal" attributeName="d" values="M 0 0 C 50 0 50 0 100 0 V 100 H 0;                         M 0 25 C 50 15 50 60 100 50 V 100 H 0;                         M 0 50 C 50 50 50 85 100 80 V 100 H 0;                         M 0 100 C 50 100 50 100 100 100 V 100 H 0" dur="0.4s" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" repeatCount="1"></animate>
  </path>
</svg>
```

I'm using it as a page transition to cover the screen in between page changes.

```
function waves2(href) {
  $('.the_box').removeClass('loaded');
  var svgLoad = $.Deferred(),
    sliderLoad = $.Deferred();
  // first animations start immediatly after svg load
  $('.ccs').load('/wordpress/wp-content/themes/Tsunami-Waves-PHP/img/waves3.svg', svgLoad.resolve);
  $('.the_box').load(href + ' .slider-transition', sliderLoad.resolve);
  // wait for both load events
  $.when(svgLoad, sliderLoad).then(function() {
    var svgDoc = $('.ccs svg');
    // delay start time of second animations if load is earlier than 0.53s
    var startTime = Math.max(0.53, svgDoc[0].getCurrentTime());
    var reveal = $('#reveal');
    // link DOM change and video play to animation beginEvent
    reveal.on('beginEvent', function() {
      $('.the_box').siblings('.slider-transition').html($('.the_box').html());
      $('.slider-transition').children('.slider-transition').unwrap();
  $('.fixedmenu, fixedmenubg').removeClass('active');
  $('.hamburger').removeClass('is-active');
      $('video').trigger('play');
    }); reveal[0].beginElementAt(startTime); $(this).addClass('loaded'); $('.woocommerce-product-gallery').each(function() {
      $(this).wc_product_gallery();
    }); slideShowInit(); initParalax();
  });
}
```

On first time loading it (after refreshing the page), the animation doesn't take place, it simply jumps to its end point without any in between. This doesn't happen on Chrome. This is the css I've applied to it

```
.svg_el{
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index:100;
}
```

The browser I'm using is Firefox Quantum 60.0.2 (64-bit) for Ubuntu

Comment: Why is this question tagged Google Chrome if the problem occurs in Firefox?

Comment: To show the different between the two.